# Overriding an interface's return type

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

here's hoping this can be done!

I have an base interface

```
interface IEntity
{
    IConfiguration Configuration {get; set;}
}
```

And an abstract class

```
abstract class Entity
{
    abstract IConfiguration Configuration {get; set;}
}
```

Now I'll introduce a "Client" that inherits from "Entity"

```
interface Client : Entity
{

}
```

Clients have a child class of "Configuration"

```
interface IClientConfiguration : IConfiguration
{

}
```

So lastly, I'd like my Client class to look like this

```
class Client : IClient
{
    public IClientConfiguration Configuration {get; set;}
}
```

The problem is, C# is complaining that I'm not returning an IConfiguration for class Client.  I can override this by declaring new public IClientConfiguration... but before I go that route, I'd like to know if there is a better way to structure this and maintain best practices.

Thanks for any help!
--Michael

Comment: Why not just return `IConfiguration`? Usual interface design would mean calling code doesn't know what is implementing the interface...

Comment: You can make `IEntity` templated which instead returns `TConfigurationType Configuration { get; set; }` and put a constraint `where TConfigurationType : IConfiguration`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [explicit interface implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in your Client class:

```
class Client : IClient
{
    public IClientConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    // Explicit implementation
    IConfiguration IEntity.Configuration 
    { 
        get { return this.Configuration; }
        set { /* what to do here? */ }
    }
}
```

This is common practice when implementing [IEnumerable<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) since that interface extend [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx). Both of these interfaces declare a method called `GetEnumerator` but with different return types (`IEnumerator<T>` vs `IEnumerator`).

However, I think you've made a design error somewhere. The configuration property is get/set. That gives the impression that your Client class must be able to accept a configuration of any kind. At the same time it seems as if your Client class only work with `IClientConfiguration` values. Confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have missed adding "IEntity" interface to your "Entity" class.

```
abstract class Entity : IEntity
{
    abstract IConfiguration Configuration {get; set;}
}
```